# Do files copied using `s3cmd sync` get affected if the original source files are eventually deleted?

Tags: linux, s3ql

A relatively inexperienced Linux user here, so sorry if this question has a pretty obvious answer and I just didn't look it up using the right terms.

Using `s3cmd sync --recursive <source> <s3-bucket>` I've copied files and folders to an S3 bucket from an existing virtual machine which will be deleted / unavailable at the end of the year. Once the VM is deleted, does that affect the files currently in the S3 bucket i.e. will these also be deleted (I'd be very surprised if yes, but thought it's worth confirming).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

That would require magical effects through the internet. No. You're not connect to S3 all the time, and it takes an *active* intervention to change anything that you stored in a bucket.

> but thought it's worth confirming

If you can't trust that level of your own reasoning, you'd have to confirm *a lot* of other things!

I think you're pretty clever, probably. Trust your own conclusions after reading gathering the facts (e.g. by reading documentation)!

Comment: Lol, thanks! Was actually asked this by a supervisor and I didn't want to say no without checking :D